# kendo grid delay loading giff

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, loading, kendo-ui

I am trying KendoUI Grid in an asp.net-mvc3 application. I would like to not display the loading giff or delay it to make it appear only after a few seconds of loading, not instantly! But I have no idea how I could do that.
Any ideas?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the built-in loading, however using the events you can do the following approach with the dataSource events:

```
var loading =false;

function start(){
    loading = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
         showLoading()//i.e. make your loading gif visible
    },2000);
}

 function end(){
    loading = false;
     hideLoading(); //hide the gif
 }


$('#gridName').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.bind('requestStart',start);
$('#gridName').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.bind('requestEnd',end);
```

Where

Comment: ok, thanks a lot Pechka. That is how I have proceeded. Actually kind of. I used the "requestStart" event to build the <div class="k-loading-mask"></div> but empty, and fill it later using a setTimeout. Then kendo closes it when the request is over. 
But thank you anyway !!